# ¿Porque me genera un error cuando quiero comparar una variable de tipo char con un caracter?

Tags: c++

Hola hice una función en C++ donde se debe ingresar caracteres que se van insertando en un set pasado por parámetro hasta que se ingrese "*".
Pero me aparece un error cuando compara el `while` (comparison between pointer and integer (`int` and `const char *`), me gustaria saber que esta mal.

```
set <char> ingresar_caracter(set <char> conjunto){
char caracter;
cout << "Ingrese un caracter (* para terminar): ";
cin >> caracter;
cout << endl;
while(caracter != "*") comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char *')
{
    conjunto.insert(caracter);
    cout << "Ingrese otro caracter (* para terminar): ";
    cin >> caracter;
    cout << endl;
}
return conjunto;
}
```

Estoy usando el  QCreator

Answer (score 3):

El error es auto-explicativo. Estás comparando un caracter con una cadena de texto.

Reemplaza

```
while(caracter != "*")
```

Por

```
while(caracter != '*')
```

Recuerda que las comillas dobles devuelven un tipo `char *` mientras que las comillas simples devuelven un tipo `char`